# How do I read/write host files from Docker container on Linux

Tags: docker

I'm using https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc-docker on Linux. I want to be able to edit my host files from within Cocalc. How do I make a folder that is a symbolic link to my host user's home?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are looking for the -v flag when starting a new container.

So something like: `docker run -v path:path -t myimage`

Comment: I think that mounts container files on host. I want host files on container.

Comment: @TimClemans No, that will mount files from the host to the container.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v-read-only

Comment: I tried ```docker run -d -v ~/cocalc:/projects -p 443:443 -v /home/main/testdocker:/projects/9bbe81b9-5ede-4987-9efe-beff316e17f2 -w /projects/9bbe81b9-5ede-4987-9efe-beff316e17f2/test -i -t  sagem
athinc/cocalc
50c751797700793cafd262ecd0a778070a55c736c07d660a415fceca3a08830f

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\\"/projects/9bbe81b9-5ede-4987-9efe-beff316e17f2/test\\\") set in config.json failed:
 not a directory\"\n".```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your local dir on to your container using docker Volumes. Here's the doc on that https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume. Here's an example `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    php-fpm:
      build: docker/php-fpm
      container_name: vendorapps-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - /localdirOnHost:/DestpathOnContainer
```